# What is pigeon computing?

Tags: search-engine, terminology

Came across the term "pigeon computing" while reading about how google works.. Can someone please elaborate on this ?.. Are pigeons really being used or am I missing something ?.. What do pigeons have to do in the design of search engines ?

Comment: It's actually a double-bluff, Google do **actually** use pigeons in ranking pages for the very reasons given in their supposed April Fools article. They successfully threw everyone off the scent by making a joke of it. If you can manage to catch a wild pigeon (domesticate are no good) then you'll find they are also spectacularly good at differential calculus and cubist painting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably referring to [PigeonRank](http://www.google.com/technology/pigeonrank.html), which is one of [Google's April Fools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%27s_hoaxes)

Comment: Man, I almost believed it. :D.

Answer (score 0):

It was an April fools joke. The actual technology is page rank.

Answer (score 0):

It was an April fools joke that google pulled